# Does iron router async load template or load everything

Tags: meteor, iron-router

May i know does iron router async load templates from server only when required or download everything in bundle at first page load.

Comment: Test it? Have you opened the debug console and looked to see when it requests files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor compiles all of your template code into javascript which is then shipped to the client in a single file in production, or in multiple files in development mode. Those files are then downloaded and interpreted on the first page load (or whenever there is a hot code push). There is currently no notion of incremental loading, however it is on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/hjBDflxp/meteor-roadmap).